# DataTable.net Move Showing 1 to top of grid

Tags: datatables

In this example I have `bPaginate = false` and I want to display two buttons and a search. I also need to add the `Showing 1 to 57 of 57 entries` to the top of the datatable. When I do this the buttons are display.

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'surname' },
            { data: 'position' },
            { data: 'office' },
            { data: 'salary' }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            }
        ],
        sDom : '<"top"lif<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ipl<"clear">>'
    } );
} );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tjmcdevitt/zsygw3d6/11/

Comment: What is your question? Also, you have 2 `dom` options: one using the newer (preferred) name of `dom` and the other using the older (deprecated) name of `sDom`. The last one found will replace the first one. (Maybe that is your question...? _Why are the buttons not displayed?_ If so, then `dom` replaced by `sDom` is the answer).

Comment: For background, see [Converting parameter names for 1.10](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).